# Button is not working inside Wizard

Tags: odoo, wizard

I am new to OpenERP, I have placed a button in wizard. But when I click on the button the wizard automatically closed without calling the function.
Can anyone explain, why?

Comment: How did you declare the button?

Comment: I declared button as "object" type.

Comment: OK, then check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have the attribute `type=object`

```
<button name="do_compute" string="Compute" type="object" icon="gtk-apply" class="oe_highlight"/>
```

The name of the method you are going to run in this example is `do_compute`. And you must return something like this:

```
@api.multi
def do_compute(self):
    self.ensure_one()

    # operations

    return {
        'context': self.env.context,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'res_model': 'your.module.name',
        'res_id': self.id,
        'view_id': False,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
    }
```

Comment: Thank you I got an idea, if I open wizard inside wizard, then it'll be solved. I Don't want to get exit from wizard. but when we press any button on wizard, it will automatically exit from the wizard.

Comment: Yes, something like that. And be careful because the `create` method is run as well.